# Gradle doesn't look for dependency in the right way

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to add moko a dependency to a kotlin multiplataform on gradle.

> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find mvvm-livedata-0.9.1-samplessources.jar (dev.icerock.moko:mvvm-livedata:0.9.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.bintray.com/icerockdev/moko/dev/icerock/moko/mvvm-livedata/0.9.1/mvvm-livedata-0.9.1-samplessources.jar

it looks like the "-samplessources" part of the link shouldn't be there, but a don't know how to remove it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would it be ok for you to download the jar and save it locally? You could tell Maven to use the downloaded version then.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but this happens on every moko dependency, and i would need  add some others dependency of this. And download and install every single one, wouldn't be practical.

Comment: I have the same problem man. It is not just problem for moko libraries but for many other libraries. I think that this samplesources.jar  files are not even needed - it is probably not problem of that libraries but problem of the Gradle plugin itself. I guess that the Gradle plugin is not able to somehow work with some libraries in KMP projects.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46153.

Answer (score 16):

**If someone else is facing a similar problem (with missing your-library-name-samplessources.jar)**
Usually, this is happening when your multiplatform project tries to consume the library, which doesn't support all the targets you have declared in your project. For example, you have an `ios()` target, while the library doesn't produce any native artifact.
To understand which targets of your projects are not covered by the library, you could try to build your project by calling

```
./gradlew build
```

You will receive a comprehensive error, describing which library variant wasn't found (`ios_x64` in my case):
[image]

Comment: FYI, I created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46153 as I believe the failure mode people are encountering is misleading.

Comment: But should it work or just the error is misleading? I have a lib which doesn't support js target, but I still want to build js target, it will just never use code from this lib. Is it possible or not really?

Comment: @KaterinaPetrova, yours is the best answer so far. Just realized that the new Kotlin Multiplatform version adds new targets for iOS. Just had to republish my library and import into my project and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved deleting jvm target from gradle, looks like moko library not support jvm yet.

versions:
kotlin 1.4.21
moko-mvvm-*: 0.9.1

Answer (score 0):

If you started getting this only recently, you might need to explicitly configure Android library variants for publishing:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("debug", "release")
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```kotlin
kotlin {
    android {
        publishAllLibraryVariants()
    }
    ...
}
```