# unable to find Kodein-db-0.8.1-beta-samplesources.jar in KMP application

Tags: build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kodein

I want to add Kodein to my application but I can't add it, it seems.

This is the error I get:

```
Could not find kodein-db-0.8.1-beta-samplessources.jar (org.kodein.db:kodein-db:0.8.1-beta).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/kodein/db/kodein-db/0.8.1-beta/kodein-db-0.8.1-beta-samplessources.jar
```

I have this in

```
sourceSets {
   val commonMain by getting {
     dependencies {
            implementation("org.kodein.db:kodein-db:0.8.1-beta")
            implementation("org.kodein.db:kodein-db-serializer-kotlinx:0.8.1-beta")
```

in my project level build.gradle.kts I have this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    val kotlinVersion = "1.4.32"
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}

extra.set("kodeinVersion", "7.2.0")

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
        maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kodein-framework/kodein-dev")
    }
}
```

I removed the last line in the `repositories` and it still failed with the same error.

Comment: This is not a Kodein-DB issue, but a KMP one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892546/gradle-doesnt-look-for-dependency-in-the-right-way

Comment: @romainbsl That solved my problem. I forgot I had some other targets in there accidentally.